# Building a script to convert XML file into JSON (with a specific format)

Tags: json, xml, powershell

I am working on a script to convert an XML output file into a JSON file with specific formatting. Below is the XML output to be converted. I am having trouble accomplishing this task and am asking what changes to the script at the bottom could I make that would accomplish this?

Snippet from `output.xml`:

```xml
<System>
<tools>
<tool_PSList>
<process>
<process>
<pid>4188</pid>
<ownersid>"S-1-5-21-3556032652-3399990904-2739522603-1001"</ownersid>
<ownername>"Bochm"</ownername>
<ownerdomain>"DESKTOP-LS0HCH3"</ownerdomain>
-<file>
<name>"C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Messaging_1.10.22012.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\SkypeHost.exe"</name>
<size>44032</size>
<attr str="ARCHIVE" hex="0x20"/>
<cert_exists>"FALSE"</cert_exists>
<cert_verified>"FALSE"</cert_verified>
<cert_result>"TRUST_E_NOSIGNATURE"</cert_result>
<cert_comment>"The file is not signed"</cert_comment>
```

The format required for the JSON output is as show below (`idealoutput.json` with the timestamp replaced by the time the script runs):

```json
{
"os":  "win",
"ts":  "timestamp here",
"value":  "C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\Microsoft.Messaging_1.10.22012.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe\\SkypeHost.exe\"; cert_comment=\"The file is not signed\"
}
```

Below is the current script I have produced in its current state it is rather broken unfortunately as this is my first week working with PowerShell, XML and JSON. I can include the other files mentioned in my script below but I am guessing there is an easier way than importing the format and then attempting to modify it with the output file so I haven't listed it here. If you'd like to see the other XML files mentioned below just let me know and I would be happy to oblige. Any insight or advice would be appreciated!

```psh
#Puts output of crowdresponse in $xml
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Bochm\Downloads\CrowdResponse\output.xml)

#Puts the formating in $format
$format = [xml](Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Bochm\Downloads\CrowdResponse\format.xml)

#Filters the output of crowdresponse into results 
$result = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file |
          Select-Object name, cert_comment

#adds the mac address to result
$result += $xml.system | Select-Object macv4

$cert_valid = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file | Where-Object {
    $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Corporation" -and
    $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and
    $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified"
} | Select-Object name, cert_comment  

$cert_invalid = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file |
    Where-Object { $_.cert_comment -match "The file is not signed" } |
    Select-Object name, cert_comment  

$node.innerXml += $cert_invalid.innerXml | Select-Object name, cert_comment

$result | ConvertTo-Json |
    Out-File "C:\Users\Bochm\Downloads\CrowdResponse\output.json"
$cert_valid | ConvertTo-Json |
    Out-File "C:\Users\Bochm\Downloads\CrowdResponse\certs_valid.json"
$cert_invalid | ConvertTo-Json |
    Out-File "C:\Users\Bochm\Downloads\CrowdResponse\certs_invalid.json"
$node | Select-Object os, ts, value, 'text' | ConvertTo-Json |
    Out-File "C:\Users\Bochm\Downloads\CrowdResponse\format.json"
```

---

Code for followup question:

```psh
$name = $xml.SelectNodes('//file') | ForEach-Object {
          $_.cert_signer -notmatch  "Microsoft Corporation" -and
          $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and
          $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified"
        } | Select-Object cert_comment

$name = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file |
        SelectNodes('//file') |
        ForEach-Object {
          $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Corporation" -and
          $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and
          $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified"
        } | Select-Object name
```

Code for hopefully the final question:

```
$xml = Get-Content 'C:\Users\Bochm\Downloads\CrowdResponse\output.xml'

$name = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file| Where-Object {
   $_.cert_signer -notmatch  "Microsoft Corporation" -and
   $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and
   $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified"
 } | ForEach-Object {
  $prop = [ordered]@{
    'os'    = 'win'
    'ts'    = (Get-Date).DateTime
    'value' = "{0}; cert_comment={1}" -f $_.name, $_.cert_comment
  }
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop
} | Select-Object name 
#$name    = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//name').'#text'
$name = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file | Where-Object {
   $_.cert_signer -notmatch  "Microsoft Corporation" -and
   $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and
   $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified"
 } | ForEach-Object {
  $prop = [ordered]@{
    'os'    = 'win'
    'ts'    = (Get-Date).DateTime
    'value' = "{0}; cert_comment={1}" -f $_.name, $_.cert_comment
  }
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop
} | Select-Object cert_comment 

$name = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file | Where-Object {
   $_.cert_signer -notmatch  "Microsoft Corporation" -and
   $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and
   $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified"
 } | ForEach-Object {
  $prop = [ordered]@{
    'os'    = 'win'
    'ts'    = (Get-Date).DateTime
    'value' = "{0}; cert_comment={1}" -f $_.name, $_.cert_comment
  }
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop
} | Select-Object name 

$name = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file| Where-Object {
   $_.cert_comment -match "The file is not signed"
 } | ForEach-Object {
  $prop = [ordered]@{
    'os'    = 'win'
    'ts'    = (Get-Date).DateTime
    'value' = "{0}; cert_comment={1}" -f $_.name, $_.cert_comment
  }
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop
} | Select-Object cert_comment 

$name = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file| Where-Object {
   $_.cert_comment -match "The file is not signed"
 } | ForEach-Object {
  $prop = [ordered]@{
    'os'    = 'win'
    'ts'    = (Get-Date).DateTime
    'value' = "{0}; cert_comment={1}" -f $_.name, $_.cert_comment
  }
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop
} | Select-Object name 
#$name    = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//name').'#text'

#$comment = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//cert_comment').'#text'

$prop = [ordered]@{
  'os'    = 'win'
  'ts'    = (Get-Date).DateTime
  'value' = "$name; cert_comment=$comment"
}

New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop |  ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "C:\Users\Bochm\Downloads\CrowdResponse\end.json"
```

Comment: Apologies, I suppose the question would be what powershell script could convert the Xml file listed above into the Json file listed below it?

Comment: There is no XML in your question, only 2 different JSON data structures.

Comment: Maybe the OP would like to avoid `\"`s in the output ?

Comment: Good catch, the initial XML file is pretty huge and I use the first line of the script to pull into an xml object before parsing with the 5th and 6th command. Here is a copy of the initial xml file. Let me know if you have other questions: 
http://pastebin.com/cAWh7Mjt

Comment: Please do not refer to external resources that may disappear at any given time. Include a representative sample in your question.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers just edited the post to include the relevant sample instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's still not quite clear to me what the desired transformation is, since your XML sample isn't well-formed, and 2 of the 3 properties from the output JSON don't seem to appear in it.

Assuming you want to extract the content of the `<name>` and `<cert_comment>` nodes and enrich it with OS and timestamp you could do something like this:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\output.xml'

$name    = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//name').'#text'
$comment = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//cert_comment').'#text'

$prop = [ordered]@{
  'os'    = 'win'
  'ts'    = (Get-Date).DateTime
  'value' = "$name; cert_comment=$comment"
}

New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop | ConvertTo-Json
```

---

**Edit:**

> ```
> $name = $xml.SelectNodes('//file') | ForEach-Object {
>           $_.cert_signer -notmatch  "Microsoft Corporation" -and
>           $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and
>           $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified"
>         } | Select-Object cert_comment
>
> $name = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file |
>         SelectNodes('//file') |
>         ForEach-Object {
>           $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Corporation" -and
>           $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and
>           $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified"
>         } | Select-Object name
> ```

These two code snippets won't work. For filtering a list of objects you need `Where-Object`, not `ForEach-Object`:

```
 ... | Where-Object {
   $_.cert_signer -notmatch  "Microsoft Corporation" -and
   $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and
   $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified"
 } | ...
```

Also, you don't want to assign a list of comments to `$name` but create a list of custom objects, so you need to do the object creation inside a `ForEach-Object` loop that you put after the filter:

```
... | ForEach-Object {
  $prop = [ordered]@{
    'os'    = 'win'
    'ts'    = (Get-Date).DateTime
    'value' = "{0}; cert_comment={1}" -f $_.name, $_.cert_comment
  }
  New-Object -Type PSCustomObject -Property $prop
} | ...
```

Comment: Wow I can't begin to thank you enough! That works almost perfectly, I have only one other question. Would it be possible to modify the code above so that 'value' contains every process with a the following cert comment:

    <cert_comment>"The file is not signed"</cert_comment>

This script will be for malware detection on Windows and I want to ensure it returns all processes with unsigned certificates. 

Again thank you for the help you have been a real life saver and your patience has been astounding. I appreciate the help and would be happy to elaborate if you have any other questions.

Comment: Sure. You'll have to select the parent node of `name` and `cert_comment`, though, and you'll have to process all of them in a loop (presumably something like `$xml.SelectNodes('//process') | ForEach-Object { ... }`).

Comment: Thanks again Ansgar,
Unfortunately having trouble getting the value field to populate. I tried using the loops shown below but to no avail:

    $name = $xml.SelectNodes('//file') | ForEach-Object{ 
    $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Corporation" -and $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified" 
        } | Select-Object cert_comment

Comment: $name = $xml.system.tools.tool_PSList.processes.process.file|SelectNodes('//file') | ForEach-Object{ 
    $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Corporation" -and $_.cert_signer -notmatch "Microsoft Windows" -and $_.cert_comment -match "The file is signed and the signature was verified" 
        }| Select-Object name

Comment: Thanks again @Ansgar Wiechers unfortunately it appears there is an issue with the output as the value field always appears empty in the Json file. Any ideas what might be preventing the

Comment: value field from populating? I have added the entire script I am now running above.

Comment: @DylanB Your loops are creating objects with 3 properties: `os`, `ts`, `value`. Then you select a property `name` (or `cert_comment`) from these objects. Why are you surprised that they show up empty? Please go find a tutorial on PowerShell so that you understand what the pipelines are actually doing. SO is not a replacement for learning the basics of the language you're using.

Comment: Apologies @AnsgarWiechers this is my first project working with PS and I honestly don't have a great understanding of the language. Any particular resources you would recommend for my issues?